# Javascript-simulate mouse over

Tags: javascript, automation, dom-events

Is it possible to simulate a `mouseover` event within the browser using JavaScript?

I've searched about it but I didn't find any useful information if this can be done

Comment: By simulate, you mean calling the mouseover event in javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes,I want to call a mouse over event in a button so the pseudo-method(i think thats the name) is activated. This button open up a list when the user put the mouse cursor over it and i want to do this without the need to put the cursor over it

Answer (score -1):

You could get the element by id and call its `mouseover` event:

```
document.getElementById('myDivId').onmouseover();
```

Or if you want to do it in jquery:

```
$('#myDivId' ).trigger('mouseenter');
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try it and update if it worked or not, thanks for the answer.I started to study javascript a few days ago so I'm kind noob yet